# Fourier Transform for triangular wave

Tags: fourier-analysis, triangles, integral-transforms

Could someone tell me if I've worked this out right? I'm unsure of the process, especially the final parts where I convert it to a sinc function.

[image: triangle wave]

Please let me know if I've made mistakes anywhere else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake on the last step:
$$
\frac{6}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ \frac {\sin^2\frac{3\omega}2}{\frac{3\omega^2}2} \right]
=
\frac{6}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ \frac {\sin^2\frac{3\omega}2}{\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{3\omega}2\right)^2} \right]
=
\frac{9}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ \frac {\sin\frac{3\omega}2}{\frac{3\omega}2} \right]^2
=
\frac{9}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  {{\rm sinc}^2\frac{3\omega}2}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I was unsure about how sinc's worked with they were squared. Does the solution look right to you for a triangle wave of this kind? :(

Comment: The answer is correct now.